# Displaying only certain photo galleries in django without id

Tags: css, django, photo

I am not very familiar with django, but I am hoping someone here will be able to tell me if something is possible.

I am currently calling the latest 4 photo galleries of a set like this:

```
{% load photogalleries %} 
                {% get_latest_galleries_from_set front-page as photo_gallery limit 4 %}
                {% for gallery in photo_gallery %}
                    <div class="rightSidePairThumb">
                        <a href="{{ gallery.get_first_photo.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{% mogrify gallery.get_first_photo.get_photo.get_photo_url resize '900x750' filter 'sharpen' %}" alt="{{ gallery.name }}" class="link"/></a>
                        <div class="rightSidePairCat">PHOTOS</div>
                        <div class="coolName"><a href="{{ gallery.get_first_photo.get_absolute_url }}">{{ gallery.name }}</a></div>
                        <hr class="style-two">
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

I no longer wish to call the 4 latest galleries all at once, but rather get one at a time in different divs on my page. So in one div, I'd like to call the latest gallery. In another div, I'd like to call just the 2nd latest gallery. In another div, just the 3rd latest gallery, etc.

I tried using 'exclude' by id, but I don't know the gallery id's. If anyone knows of a way to accomplish what I am trying to do, I would be eternally grateful.

I can accomplish this using css sibling combinators, (I do it elsewhere on my page) but the code is really long and seems... hacky. I'm hoping there is a much simpler way with django.

Again, I am not very familiar with django, so go easy on the noob.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can access specific galleries in a list by index like this:

```
{{ photo_gallery.0 }}
{{ photo_gallery.0.get_first_photo.get_absolute_url }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably accomplish what you want by using `{% if forloop.counter0 == X %}` to check which loop you are on. I'm not sure what you mean by "I dont know the gallery id's", `{{ gallery.id }}` doesn't work? Anyway..

One possibility:

```
{% for gallery in galleries %}
    <div class="{% if forloop.first %}latest-gal{% elif forloop.counter0 == 1 %}second-to-latest-gal{% elif forloop.last %}oldest-gal{% else %}third-to-latest-gal{% endif %}">
```

Although this ^ looks pretty nasty. Instead I would suggest just using `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` in your ids like:

```
{% for gallery in galleries %}
    <div id="gallery-{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
```

normally i would throw `{{ gallery.slug }}` or `{{ gallery.id }}` in the `<div id=gallery-"` but you seem to only want the latest 4 galleries so thats why I would use `{{ forloop.counter0 }}`. It will return `<div id="gallery-0">` for the latest gallery and so on.